# Grails 2.3.7 Optimistic Locking version is updated every time a Command Object is submitted

Tags: grails, grails-orm, optimistic-locking

I have the following

```
def save(ACommand command){
  ...
}

@Validateable
class ACommand implements Serializable
{
  ADomainObject bundleDef
}
```

but every time save is called the version is incremented. So if I open up two browsers and submit a different value in succession, instead of getting an error the second time as I would expect, the value is updated.

I also tried using two different sessions with no difference

**Update**

If I use breakpoints and submit before the other one is completed it works fine. However, If I let the first complete then submit the second without a refresh the version is updated to the newer one (which I don't want) and the change goes through.

**Update 2**

> When you perform updates Hibernate will automatically check the version property against the version column in the database and if they differ will throw a StaleObjectException. This will roll back the transaction if one is active.

[per Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking) this should work seems to me.

Comment: could you show the save implemenation, to see how the optimistic locking case is handled in the controller? otherwise the code snippet does not make much sense, thx :)

Comment: I am using the auto locking in Grails not sure what you want to see? It just saves an object from a form pretty basic stuff

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to check the version and handle failures yourself - it doesn't happen automatically. You can do this with code like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a boolean indicating whether the object is stale
 */
protected boolean isStale(persistedObj, versionParam = params.version) {

    if (versionParam) {
        def version = versionParam.toLong()
        if (persistedObj.version > version) {
            return true
        }
    } else {
        log.warn "No version param found for ${persistedObj.getClass()}"
    }
    false
}
```

you can call `isStale` from an action like this

```
def update() {
    Competition competition = Competition.get(params.id)

    if (isStale(competition)) {
        // handle stale object
        return
    }

    // object is not stale, so update it
}
```

Comment: 2 issues I have with this answer. 1.) This doesn't work with the scenario and a Command Object (as I showed) because on serialization it must do a get somewhere so the built in version I get is higher than it should be, meaning persistedObj.version > version is always true. Unless I do it with a breakpoint then the above works fine. 2.) I thought the whole idea of optimistic locking in Grails was to prevent creating this type of manual code?

Comment: 1) if the object is not stale then the version sent in the params should == version in the database 2) AFAIK, you need to check the version yourself, it doesn't happen automatically. If you look at the source code of a scaffolded controller you will see code similar to the above

Comment: actually I had to add a myVersion tag to the GSP to keep it too. Otherwise it automatically got incremented to the higher version. comparing the non-persisted version property to the persisted on helped me to determine if it was stale.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you expect to happen but what you describe sounds correct to me unless you have code in your save() action that is relevant.

You can't expect Hibernate to do anything special here.  When your save() action is invoked the instance is retrieved using Hibernate, mutated and then saved.  That is all fine as far as Hibernate is concerned.

One way to deal with this is when the form for editing the entity is rendered, render the version of the entity that is being edited to a hidden form field which will be submitted when the entity is saved.  In the save action after retrieving the entity from the database compare its version to the version retrieved from the hidden form field and if they don't match you know that the entity was modified between those 2 steps and you can react however is appropriate for your app.  Note that since your example is using a command object, data binding is being imposed on the entity before your code ever executes.  If that isn't what you want, don't use a command object.

I hope that helps.

Comment: In terms of the Command Object. Is there an easier form NvP serializer/deserializer for domain objects in the ecosystem?

Comment: @Jackie I am not sure what you are asking.  You can very easily serialize to/from JSON.  Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: RT but multipart forms come back as name value pairs so serializing to JSON does nothing for me until json form submits are supported

Comment: JSON form submits are supported.

Comment: Ok I thought they weren't implemented yet I can look into that.